# Removing time dependence of the Hamiltonian by transforming to a rotating frame for a three-level maser

Tags: quantum-information, hamiltonian

I was going through this paper, named [**Violating the Thermodynamic Uncertainty Relation in the Three-Level MASER**](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.07791v2). In the supplemental material, there is this calculation portion named **Steady State of The Three-Level MASER**.

The Hamiltonian under consideration: $H(t)=H_0+V(t)$, with
$$H_0=\omega_l\sigma_{ll}+\omega_u\sigma_{uu}+\omega_x\sigma_{xx}$$ and the external classical field $$V(t)=\epsilon(e^{i\omega_dt}\sigma_{lu}+e^{-i\omega_dt}\sigma_{ul}).$$
Now comes the main part of this question. They have said:

> To remove the time dependence of the Hamiltonian we transform to an appropriate rotating frame which simplifies the
> equation of motion. We define rotated operators by the unitary transformation $A^{rot}=U(t)AU^{\dagger}(t)$ with $U(t)=e^{iXt}$ and $X=\omega_l\sigma_{ll}+(\omega_l+\omega_d)\sigma_{uu}+\omega_x\sigma_{xx}$.

Here $\sigma_{mn}$ is the transition operator defined as: $\sigma_{mn}=|m><n|$.

Now by asking ChatGPT, I came to know that this transforming to a rotating system is a way to make the time-dependence of the Hamiltonian redundant. Also the necessity of unitary transformation is understandable to me.

But, (1) why the form of $X$ is such?
And for the calculation, I proceeded as follows -
\begin{align}
H^{rot}&=e^{iXt}He^{-iXt}\\
&=e^{iXt}\left(\omega_l\sigma_{ll}+\omega_u\sigma_{uu}+\omega_x\sigma_{xx}\right)e^{-iXt}+\epsilon e^{iXt}\left(e^{i\omega_dt}\sigma_{lu}\right)e^{-iXt}+\epsilon e^{iXt}\left(e^{-i\omega_dt}\sigma_{ul}\right)e^{-iXt}
\end{align}
But I can proceed no further. (2) This $\sigma_{mn}$ is an operator. What is $e^{iXt}\sigma_{mn}e^{-iXt}$?
After going through all these, the unitary part of the Lindblad Master equation changes as: $-i[H(t),\rho]\rightarrow -i[\tilde{H},\rho]$, where $\tilde{H}=H^{rot}-X$.
So finally, (3) why $\tilde{H}\ne H^{rot}?$